# How can I account for lost time in a while loop when using time.sleep

Tags: python

```
import time

def get_time():
    global time_elapsed
    time_elapsed = 0
    time_elapsed = time.time() - last_time
    return time_elapsed

def gear_encoder():
    global gear_counter, run_counter,encoder_running, sensor_state,last_time
    gear_counter = 0
    run_counter = 0
    encoder_running = False
    sensor_state = False

    encoder_running = True

    while encoder_running:
        last_time = time.time()
        if run_counter >= 320:
            print("END")
            break
        if sensor_state == True and gear_counter <= 5:
            sensor_state = not sensor_state
            gear_counter += 1
            run_counter += 1
            #print("State is " + str(sensor_state))
            time.sleep((1.0/24) - get_time())

        elif sensor_state == False and gear_counter <= 5:
            sensor_state = not sensor_state
            gear_counter += 1
            run_counter += 1
            #print("State is " + str(sensor_state))
            time.sleep((1.0/24) - get_time())

        elif sensor_state == True and gear_counter <= 8:
            sensor_state = not sensor_state
            gear_counter += 1
            run_counter +=1
            #print("State is " + str(sensor_state))
            time.sleep((1.0/72) - get_time())

        elif sensor_state == False and gear_counter <= 8:
            sensor_state = not sensor_state
            gear_counter += 1
            run_counter +=1
            #print("State is " + str(sensor_state))
            time.sleep((1.0/72) - get_time())

        else:
            gear_counter = 0

start_time = time.time()

gear_encoder()

end_time = time.time() - start_time

print("The sensor changed states " + str(run_counter) + " times")
print(str(end_time))
```

So this is the code that I've got so far. If it runs this is it's output.

```
END
The sensor changed states 320 times
10.504526853561401
```

So what I attempted to set up was function called get_time() that will find the difference in time from when the variable last_time is called to when the actual function is called. The goal of this was to account for the time it takes to change the sensor_state and add to the counter variables in the sleep function.

You could do the math yourself but when this loops through 320 times all the time.sleeps that the program runs through add up to 10 seconds. I want the program to end in as close to 10 seconds as possible which is why I tried to account for the extra time with the get_time() function by subtracting the time it took to change sensor state and add to the counters.

My question to you all is, do you know of any methods that could help me lower this time drift? Was my technique to account for lost time even a valid approach? I would like to at some point add variables as arguments into time.sleep and probably lower the sleep to even smaller values than (1.0/72) seconds. Might multi threading be an option here? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I'd give in code is pretty extensive. Let's see if I can get you on the path. You probably don't want to use sleep, because it blocks and everything becomes serial. That's important because you stated you want to exit in as close to 10 seconds as possible. That's fairly straightforward, if you don't have blocking calls going on. The other timers can be set up similarly. I show some examples below. Set up a timer to exit in 10 seconds. Note that the timer that is set for 11 seconds will not occur because the exit occurs before it triggers. This must be run as a script -- not interactively.

```
import sched, time, sys

def myExit():
    # Do stuff here
    sys.exit()

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
# This causes the program to exit...
s.enter(10, 1, myExit, ())
s.enter(2.0/5, 2, print_answer, (1,))
s.enter(3.0/5, 2, print_answer, (2,))
s.enter(11, 2, print_answer, (3,))
s.run()
```

Comment: so essentially I can have the scheduler handle when to execute certain bits of code without having to stop the program momentarily with time.sleep()? If so I'll give a try towards implementing this into my program.

Comment: Your statement is correct. Though there is some time required for the triggered function to complete. But you **can** guarantee that the program will exit whenever you schedule it.

Comment: So I got my program working with scheduling and it got rid of almost all of the undesirable lag. The way i did it in my program was I made a loop that makes as many scheduled events as I want it to. Then after that loop exits I ran them. I made 320 schedules to get to 10 seconds. If I want the program to run for minutes at a time will the amount of schedules I would need to create be a problem?

Comment: You'll find that event systems are very efficient. However, the only way to tell is to queue up a bunch and see. If the number of events begins to cause a lag in performance, you could consider multiprocessing (threading won't help because your single core that your process is running in would be busy handling too many events already).